# Implement Draft JS into Next JS, Text Editor Won't Show

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to implement draft js as text editor into my next.js project. I have implemented all code based on official guide but the text editor won't show. Here is my code

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { useRouter, Router } from 'next/router';
import Layout from '../../components/MyLayout';
import Settings from '../../components/Settings';
import MyEditor from '../../components/TextEditor';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

const Post = (props) => {
    const router = useRouter();
    const object = props.post.data[0];
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>{object.title}</h1>
      <div className="p-2 border bg-light text-right text-dark">Oleh: {object.username}</div>
      <MyEditor/>
    </Layout>
  );
}

Post.getInitialProps = async function(context) {
    const {id} = context.query;
    const FormData = new URLSearchParams();
    FormData.append('slug',`${id}`);
    const res = await fetch(Settings.api+'viewPost',{
        'method': 'POST',
        'body': FormData
    });
    const post = await res.json();
    console.log('aw');
    return {
        post
    };
};

export default Post;
```

**TextEditor.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';

export default function MyEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = React.useState(
    EditorState.createEmpty()
  );

  return (
    <Editor
      editorState={editorState}
      onChange={setEditorState}
    />
  );
}
```

I really appreciate any answer. Thank you

Comment: please how did you resolve it ?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you're doing the right thing - Draft-js is very much a low-level editing tool that you can build rich text-editing on top of - I'm guessing that the editor is actually rendering on the page, but you haven't added any toolbars or complex initial state so you're just seeing a blank page.

I reproduced a super basic Next JS example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-swirles-7nmbf?file=/pages/index.js and you'll see that the editor itself is 'invisible' as there is no styling applied and no toolbar. If you look further into the Draft-js docs you'll see you can apply initial config objects that will give it a basic style (which you can further customize as you wish).

Comment: How do you apple basic style? The style and className properly do nothing.

Comment: Hey @Shamoon - in the time that I played around with Draft-js I also found styling unintuitive - you can actually apply changes a css (or sass / less) file e.g. style.css, targeting the Draft editor with the appropriate classes. For example - you can use the browser console or docs to find the relevant classes e.g. .DraftEditor-root and then apply styles as you would in any css stylesheet - there's a detailed example of styling Draft-js in this article: https://dev.to/tumee/how-to-style-draft-js-editor-3da2